# array type required in indexed component ADA

Tags: arrays, compilation, ada, subtype

Alright, so i'm writing a program that's designed to compare 7 digit inputs to a known set of seven digit inputs and find the distances between them. Everything compiles fine except for the fact that I'm getting an error that states that "array type required in indexed component"

```
  pickbit1:
  FOR X IN 1 .. 7 LOOP
  pickdigit1:
  FOR Y IN 0 .. 9 LOOP
     IF a1(X) /= Compare(Y)(X) THEN
        d1(X)(Y) := d1(X)(Y) + 1;
     END IF;
  END LOOP pickdigit1;
END LOOP Pickbit1;
```

The error occurs at the line in which the second for loop is created. I have no idea why there would be an error referring to an index of an array there.
Here are my array types.

```
subtype segment is Character range '0' .. '1';
subtype distance is Integer;
subtype c is Character range ' ' .. ' ';
type Segment_Array is array(1 .. 7) of segment;
type Digit_Array is array(1 .. 7) of Character range '0' .. '1';
type Compare_Array IS array(0 .. 9) of Digit_Array;
type Distance_Array IS array(0 .. 9) of distance;
type Total_Array IS array(0 .. 9, 0 .. 9) of Integer;
```

a1 a Segment_Array, d1 is a Distance_Array and Compare is a Compare_Array

Comment: You came *so* close to giving us a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org). And I recommend `-gnatfl` for source listings with embedded error messages.

Answer (score 2):

if `d1` is a `Distance_Array`, `d1(X)` returns a `distance` (subtype of `Integer`). An `Integer` (or a `distance`) is not an array type and cannot be indexed further, and so the compiler complains when you're trying to do `d1(X)(Y)`. 
I don't know why the compiler complains about the line where the loop is created, it should complain about the line:

```
d1(X)(Y) := d1(X)(Y) + 1;
```

Comment: When I tried it, the compiler did complain about the line you indicate.